# Docker, System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate

Tags: centos, docker

I am trying to create docker container for one of the centos service created by us.

We have 2 rpm files.

After installing on base image of centos 8.

I installed those 2 rpm files in it.

But, when I try to start the service, I am getting this error. when I ran
systemctl start <service_name>

System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate

Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

Based, on the feedback of different posts, I tried creating container with below steps.

docker run -it -p 8080:80 -p 16700:16700 centos

docker run -it -p 8080:80 -p 16700:16700 --privileged=true centos

Both same issue. Please suggest.

Answer (score 7):

Docker is designed around the idea of a single service per container. While there are workarounds to get systemd running in a container those are AFAIK only useful in the context of ci test jobs.

Instead of starting the process with `systemctl` find the actual command executed by `systemd` when running `systemctl start servicename` by looking for the `ExecStart` instruction in the unit file of the service. That is the command (you might need to adjust it a bit) which should be set as the `CMD` instruction in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Can you give the command to check the service target

Comment: You can find the path to the unit file (`servicename.service`) by running `systemctl status servicename` the path should be in the 2nd line.

Comment: It is showing a sh file in the ExecStart.
When I ran that sh, it is not showing any output.

But, below is the contents of the sh file.
https://codeshare.io/anZROX

Comment: This answer really helps.